# How to set the environment variable in Scrapy code of python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to use scrapy using proxy connection and want to use both http and https as [here](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy) says. The most simple way is to set the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy. But I have some conflict using my company system if I set the variables. Instread I want to put these settings to the python code.

So, I use HttpProxyMiddleWare Scrapy provides and wrote some code like the followings.

```
import base64

class ProxyMiddleWare(object):
    def process_reqeust(self, reqeust, spider):

        http_proxy = "http://70.10.15.12:8080"
        https_proxy = "https://70.10.15.12:8080"

        proxyDict = {
            "http"  : http_proxy,
            "https" : https_proxy
        }
        reqeust.meta['proxies'] = proxyDict
```

And I added the HttpProxyMiddleWare in setting.py like the followings.

```
# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'test.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    #'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware' : 1,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware' : 543
}
```

But it didn't work. give me some workaround. Thanks :)

Comment: u figure this out??

Comment: No, I couldn't . sorry for late

Answer (score 0):

A bit late perhaps but someone else may use the idea.

Adding 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware' means, using the default proxy middleware of scrapy.

To activate your own middleware, you should set it like:

'your_project_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleWare' : 543

I hope it helps.